# Unable to serialize in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Stripping the code to bare essentials, I have a form

```
name="addPageForm" id="addPageForm" method="get"
```

and I have an input type="text"

```
name="categoryTxt" id="categoryTxt"
```

This is my script

```
<script>
var strData = $('#addPageForm').serialize();
alert(strData);
</script>
```

The alert shows

```
categoryTxt=
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You've stripped a bit too much.  What's the value of your textbox, and are you sure you just don't have a typo like "<inptu" ?

Comment: I guess you are submitting form on pageLoad when your "categoryTxt" is empty that's why alert shows nothing... you can do two thing 1) submit form after input in your textbox OR 2) set default value into your textbox

Comment: no you can not update this way, you ask another question read stakeoverflow ASK QUESTION FAQ.

Comment: Thanks @user3321823. I had since resolved that problem of form not getting serialized by submitting the form after textbox input. The question stands edited now.

Comment: @user1153551 I am sorry. I was not aware of this.

Comment: no problem you ask again ajax question if you need help then. Stackoverflow always ready to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why Unable to serialize and how to i serialize** - Reason behind your **alert box** popup when page load so at that time your input is empty so alert empty value,
But you can try trigger way when you click **submit** to alert your form data by this **following way**,

#### Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/472Cw/)**</kbd>

#### jQuery

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var strData = $('#addPageForm').serialize();
    console.log(strData);
    alert(strData);
});
```

#### HTML

```
<form name="addPageForm" id="addPageForm" method="get">
    <input name="categoryTxt" id="categoryTxt" />
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: Thanks @user1153551. I figured that out just as soon as I hit the Ask Question button. :p Question edited.

Answer (score 1):

The textfield doesn't have a value, therefore the field is displayed as empty.

```
<form name="addPageForm" id="addPageForm" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="categoryTxt" id="categoryTxt" value="text" />
</form>

<script>
var strData = $('#addPageForm').serialize();
alert(strData);
</script>
```

will show

```
categoryTxt=text
```

Comment: Thanks @akirk. I figured that out just as soon as I hit the Ask Question button. :p
Question edited.